# How to get the modified date and year of file in Unix?

Tags: bash, unix

I am looking for a command to get the modified date of file in Unix including the year.
Currently when I am using `ls -lrt A.sh`
we get following details:
-rwxrwSrwx 1 infprdbi bis 34816 Jan 31 15:44 A.sh

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can specify the time format via `--time-style` option:

```
ls -la --time-style=full-iso
ls -la --time-style=+%Y-%m-%d
```

Comment: I get `ls: illegal option -- -`

Comment: `--time-style` doesn't seem to be available on macOS, use `ls -la -D %Y-%m-%d` instead.

Comment: -D fails on MacOs.  ls: illegal option -- D
usage: ls [-@ABCFGHLOPRSTUWabcdefghiklmnopqrstuwx1%] [file ...]