# Date and time of a file in Unix in a desired format

Tags: unix, unix-timestamp, ls

Can anyone tell me what is the command  to print out file creation TIME  and DATE in UNIX? I have searched a lot on Google and got the solution for Linux. But those commands are not working on Sun OS.

Comment: Which UNIX? There are many

Comment: SunOS (5.10) is my UNIX OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unix doesn't have a file creation time.  It has these:

- last modified time (content was modified)
- last inode or files status change time (attributes like permissions, number of links etc., were changed)
- last access time (content was read)

`ls` is the best option if you are not feeding the output to a program. `man ls` is your friend.

```
ls -lu => show last access time
ls -lc => show last status change time
ls -l  => show last modified time (default)
```

In general, it is not recommended that we feed the output of `ls` into a program because of portability concerns.  On macOS and Linux systems, we have a `stat` command to extract file status information.

---

Related posts:

[Print a file's last modified date in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16391208/print-a-files-last-modified-date-in-bash)

[How to get the modified date and year of file in Unix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41994368/how-to-get-the-modified-date-and-year-of-file-in-unix?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[How to get file creation time in Unix with Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26326589/how-to-get-file-creation-time-in-unix-with-perl?rq=1)

Comment: Is there any way like I create a file with( touch filename) command in Unix and then I hit ( ls -lrt ) so can I read the time and date that is shown to me at that time in complete format I have this urgent requirement is there any solution or its simply not possible????

Comment: If you are coding in Perl, Ruby, or Python, it should be easy - all these languages have a `stat` equivalent.

Comment: No,i need it in UNIX only. I guess this is going to be a real big challenge for me now..:d anyways thanks a lot for all the information and help..(y)

Comment: Perl, Ruby, and Python -- all of them are available on Unix.

Comment: Yaaa but I am not working on either of them.I am working on SIEBEL where we have server on  UNIX OS.And I am writing a shell script where I need to read some  file date and time to get the script  done.